# How do I write this vb.net/linq select more performant?

Tags: vb.net, linq, ado

I have a list of persons "Gezinslijst" and the head of the family "Klanten". I want to fill a list with all persons and get a list of the family with a list property containing his family members.

This works, but takes 30-60 seconds to load. I know it's because I have to filter 2600 times to get the list, but I don't know how to write it more efficiently.

```
Private Sub Initialize()
        Dim Gezinslijst As List(Of GetClientsGezin_Result) = New List(Of GetClientsGezin_Result)
        Gezinslijst = (From k In db.GetClientsGezin() Select k).ToList()

        Dim Klanten As List(Of Klanten) = New List(Of Klanten)
        Klanten = (From k In db.GetClients() Select New Klanten With {
                                                 .Naam = k.Naam,
                                                 .Status = k.Status,
                                                 .Prefix = k.Prefix,
                                                 .Rijksregisternr = k.Rijksregisternr,
                                                 .Saldo = k.Saldo,
                                                 .SubCategorie = k.SubCategorie,
                                                 .Straat = k.Straat,
                                                 .Huisnr = k.Huisnr,
                                                 .Busnr = k.Busnr,
                                                 .Postcode = k.Postcode,
                                                 .Plaats = k.Plaats,
                                                 .Land = k.Land,
                                                 .ID_Key = k.ID_Key,
                                                 .Gezinsleden = Gezinslijst.Where(Function(x) x.ID_DiftarClient = k.ID_Key).ToList()
        }).ToList()
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: You can convert the `Gezinslijst` into a dictionary using `ID_DiftarClient` as the key. Other than that you are selecting everything without filtering anything so there is not that much to optimize.

Comment: How do i make a dictionary from it or if theres not much to opitmize how would you do it from scratch?

Comment: Is the return type of db.GetClientsGezin() IQueryable?

Comment: Yes it is what should i do then?

Comment: When you call `ToList` you are immediately executing the query and dumping all of the results into a local list object.  Depending on your usage, it might be better to keep the result as an `IEnumerable` without immediately realizing it into a list.

Comment: What are  `db.GetClientsGezin()` and `db.GetClients()` exactly? You have the `ado` tag, and it would help to see what those functions are doing. Are you simply returning recordsets? If so, then you can't optimize anything server side with these recordsets, and all the filtering must be done client side. This could probably be done server side with a view more efficiently.

Comment: Ill try the IEnumerable. They are stored procedures @djv